# node cant find module even though is installed in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, node-modules

Im trying to use pdf-parse module but after installing it, node isnt able to find the module. Already tryied deleting and running yarn install but didnt fixed the issue. Also i can see the module installed in package.json

[image: Here is pdf-parse in node-modules]
[image: Type definitions for pdf-parse]

Here is the type definitions for the module.
And the module it-self

[image: error]

```
import pdfParse from 'pdf-parse';

pdfParse(dataChunk).then((data) => {
      console.log(data.info);
    });
```

Here it is how i use it but it doesnt work

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "module": "commonjs",
 "declaration": true,
 "removeComments": true,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "esModuleInterop": true,
 "target": "es2017",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "outDir": "./dist",
 "baseUrl": "./",
 "incremental": true
 }
}
```

Comment: try `import * as pdfParse from 'pdf-parse';`

Comment: Tryied it before, tryied it again and didnt work

Comment: Hm, okay you can also try `require` like `const parse = require('pdf-parse')`

Comment: Still doesnt find it

Comment: btw, have you added `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pdf-parse`?

Comment: Yes, already added

Comment: What is your env? node.js, or? Seems like node from pkg.json, but wont hurt to ask)

Comment: Im using node.js with typescript

Comment: Also can you show you tsconfig.json?

Comment: yeah, strange, works fine by me with `import * as parse from 'pdf-parse';`, tsconfig is the same, but with target to es2016, which probably shouldn't matter. But the problem is with typescript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved my problem using `docker compose up -d --build`